# Is it necessary to fill action attribute in django template form if using Generic View

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I am using django Generic views which straigt way loads the create form.
I have seen that even if i don't enter anything in template form action attribute , the data still gets in database.

So i want to know that how does django know show to enter stuff in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSTing to the same URL does not require the `action` attribute to be specified, and omitting it altogether is the best solution.

Comment: The problem is i want to use jquery form plugin to post , so will it automatically get that address

Comment: And you only thought about bringing this up now?

Comment: Well if the answer to my question was no , then there was no need for asking that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think my answer says "yes".

Comment: I got that from `does not require`